# Simple way to group the list-indices of equal elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering

I am looking for a simple way to group the list-indices of equal elements of a list. Examples:

```
{1,2,3,3} -> {{1}, {2}, {3,4}}
(the elements at positions 1 and 2 are unique, and those at positions 3 and 4 are equal)

{f,f,g,g,f} -> {{1,2,5}, {3,4}}
(the elements at positions 1,2,5 are equal, and those at positions 3 and 4 are equal)
```

For now my code is

```
F[L_] := Values@GroupBy[MapIndexed[List, L], First -> Last, Flatten]
```

or

```
G[L_] := GatherBy[MapIndexed[List, A], First][[All, All, 2, 1]]
```

both of which look very clumsy.
Is there a direct way to group? Something along the lines of

```
GroupBy[L, First -> index]
```

maybe?

## benchmarks

Thanks for all the contributions! Here's a ranking by runtime for specific parameters:

```
L = RandomInteger[{0, 10^3}, 10^6];

(* Carl's ResourceFunction call (run twice to get timing right) *)
a1 = Values@ResourceFunction["GroupByList"][Range@Length@L, L]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* Chris's simplest call *)
a2 = Values@PositionIndex[L]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* ubpdqn *)
a3 = Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[#2[[1]], #1] &, L]][[2]]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* my second crummy suggestion *)
a4 = GatherBy[MapIndexed[List, L], First][[All, All, 2, 1]]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* my first crummy suggestion *)
a5 = Values@GroupBy[MapIndexed[List, L], First -> Last, Flatten]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* KennyColnago *)
a6 = Map[SequencePosition[L, {#}][[All, 1]] &, DeleteDuplicates[L]]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* OkkesDulgerci *)
a7 = Flatten /@ (Position[L, #] & /@ DeleteDuplicates@L); //AbsoluteTiming//First

(*     0.028881 s for a1    *)
(*     0.086623 s for a2    *)
(*     0.997497 s for a3    *)
(*     1.44011  s for a4    *)
(*     1.8618   s for a5    *)
(*    13.86     s for a6    *)
(*    31.6595   s for a7    *)

a1 == a2 == a3 == a4 == a5 == a6 == a7
(*    True    *)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
Values[PositionIndex[list]]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) [`GroupByList`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GroupByList) to do this:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 3};
ResourceFunction["GroupByList"][Range @ Length @ list, list]
```

> <|1 -> {1}, 2 -> {2}, 3 -> {3, 4}|>

```
list = {f, f, g, g, f};
ResourceFunction["GroupByList"][Range @ Length @ list, list]
```

> <|f -> {1, 2, 5}, g -> {3, 4}|>

Use [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values) to convert the [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association) to a list.

Comment: Is this still faster than `PositionIndex`?

Comment: @CATrevillian yes much faster, see benchmarks above.

Answer (score 4):

You can also used [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)/[`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html), e.g.

```
pi[u_] := Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[#2[[1]], #1] &, u]][[2]]
```

So `pi[{f, f, g, g, f}]` yields

> {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4}}

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is simple enough but here is one way to do it.

```
L = {1, 2, 3, 3};
G[L_] := Flatten /@ (Position[L, #] & /@ DeleteDuplicates@L)
G[L]
```

> {{1}, {2}, {3, 4}}

```
  L = {f,f,g,g,f};
  G[L]
```

> {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4}}

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `SequencePosition` looks like:

```
GroupListIndices[a_List] := Map[SequencePosition[a, {#}][[All, 1]]&, DeleteDuplicates[a]]
```